# Magento not writing to log files

Tags: magento, logging, magento-1.9

My Magento installation suddenly stopped writing to log files.
If I try to output the following:

```
Mage::log('Test', null, 'test.log');
```

Magento creates this file but it's empty.

Logging is activated in settings -> developer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get the log working again.
Although caching was disabled clearing it and clearing the sessionfolder and adding 777 permission to the log folder recursively the log started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Mage::log('Test', null, 'test.log', true);
```